# Moment incorrectly validates times or did I miss something?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Trying to use momentjs to validate time input, but either I miss something or there is a bug, please give a hand to figure out the case

```
var time = moment("13:22rrr", 'HH:mm','en', true)
time.isValid() //true
var time1 = moment('03:a5jojojo', 'HH:mm',true)
time1.isValid() //true
```

Moment considers these times as valid ones.

Comment: [These are both false when I try](http://jsfiddle.net/8ptuarth/)

Comment: I was just about to say what @DavidHedlund said.

Comment: Which version of momentjs are you using? The output is `false` using the lastest one (`2.19.1`) as shown in David's fiddle.

Comment: I tried using version  2.2.1
http://jsfiddle.net/sjdfhftv/